# How to get the rate of INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT statements in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, performance, performancecounter

I want to know the rate of `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE and SELECT` statements in SQL Server. For example, something such as *100 INSERTs per second*. Is this possible? I searched through the SQL Server related performance counters and didn't find anything interesting. Hope someone can point me to the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Edit

I'm doing some monitoring task with SQL Server. My MySQL DBA colleagues seem can grab this data from MySQL very easily. I were asked to provide the same data but for SQL Server. Basically I'm asking a way to get the number of INSERTs happened in last second, minute etc. It's instance level metric and is the sum of all INSERTs for all databases.

Comment: rate? you mean execution time. you can use  sql profile to collect the statement and time

Comment: Every INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and SELECT statement will be different. All you can do is TRY them against REAL LIFE data samples to get an idea.

Comment: This is a DBA question; not a programming question.

Comment: This isn't even a real question. It is impossible to provide an answer to this. There is not a fixed number of allowed statements per minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really is no single answer to this question as the rate of INSERTs will vary wildly based on the tables being inserted into and how wide (in bytes) the rows are that have data inserted into them.

For example, tables that contain large columns that are xml, images, varchar(max)'s, Unicode strings such as nchar and nvarchar, or a filestream will take much longer than a table with a couple of int and varchar columns.

So either give us a concrete table schema that you're inserting into, or the answer is a solid 'it depends'.